# Erro em query - Dados inconsistentes NCLOB

Tags: sql, query, oracle, oracle11c

Olá,

Estou tentando realizar uma consulta em um banco de dados Oracle e está retornando um erro

> ORA-00932: tipos de dados inconsistentes: esperava - obteve NCLOB
>   00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

A query é a seguinte:

```
SELECT      DISTINCT SQL1.JOBNAME
        ,   SQL1.COMPILATION
        ,   SQL1.FOLDERPATH
        ,   SQL2.JOBSHORTDESCRIPTION
        ,   SQL2.JOBLONGDESCRIPTION
FROM        (
                SELECT      DISTINCT JOBNAME
                        ,   FOLDERPATH
                        ,   MAX(COMPILATIONTIMESTAMP) AS COMPILATION
                FROM        JOBEXEC
                WHERE       PROJECTNAME = 'MDM_PRD'
                        AND FOLDERPATH  NOT LIKE '%Temporario%'
                        AND JOBNAME     NOT LIKE '%Copy%'
                        AND JOBNAME     NOT LIKE '%Teste%'
                GROUP BY    JOBNAME
                        ,   FOLDERPATH
                        ,   COMPILATIONTIMESTAMP
            )       SQL1
INNER JOIN  JOBEXEC SQL2 ON SQL1.JOBNAME = SQL2.JOBNAME
```

Essa base de dados grava as informações conforme o JOBNAME recebe uma compilação, criando vários registros com o mesmo nome no campo JOBNAME, para isso é necessário dar um DISTINCT no JOBNAME para que me traga apenas um registro, porém quando os campos JOBSHORTDESCRIPTION e JOBLONGDESCRIPTION estão dentro do select, retorna o erro reportado acima.

Eu preciso fazer a construção dessa query puxando todas as informações sem repetições, mas ainda com a descrição, alguém saberia me auxiliar em como posso reconstruir essa query?

[image: Estrutura da tabela JOBEXEC]

Comment: Uma questão: as colunas `JOBSHORTDESCRIPTION` e `JOBLONGDESCRIPTION` é suposto armazenarem texto apenas? Porquê declará-las como `NCLOB`?

Comment: @JoãoMartins, o NCLOB também é para armazenar de texto, mas este aceita charsets diferentes do padrão do banco definido no nls_parameters

Comment: Na verdade esses campos do DB foram definidos por padrão no momento da instalação da ferramenta da IBM, então não é possível realizar a alteração